# writeToFile fails with error = null

Tags: ios, nsfilehandle, xcode6.4

I have an app running in the XCode simulator (v6.4); this is the pertinent code:

```
            NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        //  read the file back into databuffer...
        NSFileHandle *readFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Backup.txt"]];
        NSData *databuffer = [readFile readDataToEndOfFile];
        [readFile closeFile];

        // compress the file
        NSData *compressedData = [databuffer gzippedData] ;

        // Write to disk
        NSString *outputPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@.zip", documentsPath, venueName, strDate];
        _BackupFilename = fileName;  //  save for upload

        NSFileHandle *outputFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:outputPath];
        NSError *error = nil;

        //  write the data for the backup file
        BOOL success = [compressedData writeToFile: outputPath options: NSDataWritingAtomic error: &error];

        if (error == nil && success == YES) {
            NSLog(@"Success at: %@",outputPath);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to store. Error: %@",error);
        }

        [outputFile closeFile];
```

I'm trying to create a backup of a file by taking the file, compressing it and then writing it out.  I get an error *Failed to store. Error: (null)*);  why is it failing without returning the error code?

Comment: Hi Rick... the output file is used as input to a "restore" function... I'll make the changes and get back to you...

NOTE:  I just saved my comment and now ALL of your's are gone?  How do I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong here. To start. change your `if` statement to:

```
if (success) {
```

Never explicitly compare a `BOOL` value to `YES` or `NO`.

You also never use `outputFile` so remove that code. It may interfere with the call to `writeToFile:`.

And there's no point in using the file handle to read the data. Just use `NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:`.

And don't build paths using `stringWithFormat:`.

Overall, I would write your code as:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

//  read the file back into databuffer...
NSString *dataPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Backup.txt"]];
NSData *databuffer = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];

// compress the file
NSData *compressedData = [databuffer gzippedData];

// Write to disk
NSString *outputName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.zip", venueName, strDate];
NSString *outputPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:outputName];

//  write the data for the backup file
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [compressedData writeToFile:outputPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

if (success) {
    NSLog(@"Success at: %@",outputPath);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to store. Error: %@",error);
}
```

Since `success` is still `NO` and `error` is still `nil`, then most likely this means that `compressedData` is `nil`. This probably means that `databuffer` is `nil` which means that there is no file named `Backup.txt` (case matters) in the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Using your code, I get the same thing ( Failed to store. Error: (null))

Comment: Then most likely `compressedData` is `nil` which could mean that `databuffer` is `nil` which means that there is no file named `Backup.txt` in the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Thanks Rick... I'll follow that up...  :D

Comment: Please don't iuse `+ dataWithContentsOfFile:`, use `+ dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` with an error parameter so that if there is an error the reason is available inthe error parameter.